# Why is it called the "cake pattern"

Tags: scala, design-patterns, mixins

I've looked on a lot of blog posts today, and while there are a lot of people explaining how to use the class, I can't find an original source that explains why it's called that.  I assume it's some kind of pun on "mixin"?

Is there a place where the pattern is defined and the name explained?

Answer (score 2):

You can find a short definition in **Programming in Scala** by *Martin Odersky* http://www.artima.com/shop/programming_in_scala_2ed .

Detailed information can be found in 
**real-world scala: dependency injection (di)**  by *Jonas Bonér*  which might be the first mention of the pattern http://jonasboner.com/real-world-scala-dependency-injection-di/

The name describes the layered design as layers in a cake.

Comment: Yeah, I saw the Jonas Bonér article, which explains how to use the pattern, but not why it's called "cake".  I'll take a look at the Odersky book.  Thanks!